# Using Python LXML to removing XML element values but leaving one placeholder

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an XML file which I would like to clear the text in the 'value' child elements, but leave one empty value element as a placeholder for adding text at a later date.  I am using Python's LXML module.

Here's an example of the XML section:

```
<spec class="Spec" name="New Test">
    <mainreport>
        <item name="New Item">First Item</item>
    </mainreport>

    <case class="CaseItem" name="Some Name">
        <extraelement>
            <item name="ID">Some Id</item>

        </extraelement>

        <pool class="String" name="Originator">
            <value>A</value>
            <value>B</value>
            <value>C</value>
        </pool>

        <pool class="String" name="Target">
            <value>D</value>
            <value>E</value>
            <value>F</value>
        </pool>
```

And here's what I am hoping to output:

```
<spec class="Spec" name="New Test">
    <mainreport>
        <item name="New Item">First Item</item>
    </mainreport>

    <case class="CaseItem" name="Some Name">
        <extraelement>
            <item name="ID">Some Id</item>

        </extraelement>

        <pool class="String" name="Originator">
            <value></value>
        </pool>

        <pool class="String" name="Target">
            <value></value>
        </pool>
```

I have written the following code, but it only adds the **"value"** tag to the last element:

```
import lxml.etree as et
import os

xml_match = os.path.join("input.xml")
doc = et.parse(xml_match)

for elem in doc.xpath('//case/pool/value'):
    elem.getparent().remove(elem)

blankval = et.Element("value")
blankval.text = ""

for elem in doc.xpath('//case/pool'):
    elem.insert(1, blankval)

outFile = "output.xml"

doc.write(outFile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove all `value` elements and append an empty one in a single loop:

```
for elem in doc.xpath('//case/pool'):
    for value in elem.findall("value"):
        elem.remove(value)

    blankval = et.Element("value")
    blankval.text = ""
    elem.append(blankval)
```

There is also a handy [`.clear()` method](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html), but it would also clear up the attributes.

---

The reason your current approach is not working is because you are trying to reuse the same exact `blankval` element, but instead, you need to recreate new element in the loop before you perform an insert operation:

```
for elem in doc.xpath('//case/pool'):
    blankval = et.Element("value")
    blankval.text = ""
    elem.insert(1, blankval)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @alecxe, this makes sense now.  Like you say, and Ironically I was trying to simplify the task by trying to break the process down into two loops, which actually hindered my initial attempt.